# Problems with setting up the jooq Generator 3.17.5 for PRO Version

Tags: oracle, jooq, oracle-autonomous-db, jooq-codegen

I currently have the problem that I cannot get the jooq Generator to run. As a template I used the example from Etienne Studer (see https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/tree/master/example/configure_toolchain_gradle_dsl). That means I am using Gradle and Java 17.

The payed Pro Libraries from jooq (I use a local postgresql DB) are located in a subfolder (lib) in the project (see line 11 in build.gradle file.

My gradle file looks like this:

```
import nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqEdition

plugins {
  id 'nu.studer.jooq' version '8.0'
  id 'java'
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  flatDir {
    dirs 'lib'
  }
}

dependencies {
  jooqGenerator 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.0'
}

jooq {
  version = '3.17.5'
  edition = JooqEdition.PRO

  configurations {
    main {
      generationTool {
        logging = org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Logging.TRACE
        jdbc {
          driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
          url = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres'
          user = 'postgres'
          password = 'blabla'
        }
        generator {
          name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator'
          database {
            name = 'org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase'
            inputSchema = 'public'
          }
          generate {
            deprecated = false
            records = false
            immutablePojos = false
            fluentSetters = true
          }
          target {
            packageName = 'solar.deinland.importxml.postgresql'
          }
          strategy.name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error message that I get when running the gradle task to generate the code is:

```
Error: Could not initialize main class org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool
Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jooq/meta/SchemaVersionProvider

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

The above shown gradle task runs fine as long as I change the edition to JooqEdition.OSS. If I want to use the paid libs I run into the above mentioned error.

Is it ok just to place the libraries in a project subfolder and reference them as `flatdir`? Or do I need to setup a local maven repository?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Cheers
Knut

Comment: Perhaps a regression in a recent version of that third party plugin? The plugin is mainly based on the jOOQ Open Source Edition, which has the Maven `groupId` `org.jooq`. In your case, the `groupId` should be e.g. `org.jooq.pro`. You could check that by adding explicit dependencies for `jooqGenerator`. This shouldn't be required with the `edition` configuration, but again, it might be a regression...?

Comment: Thanks @LukasEder! I'll check that.

Comment: The problem is solved. As soon as I run the the maven-import batch file that is provided with jooq the code does what it should.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by running the "maven_install" batch script that is provided with the jooq libraries. This script registers the provided libraries to the local maven instance. Replacing the entry

```
flatDir {
  dirs 'lib'
}
```

with

```
mavenLocal()
```

gives gradle the oportunity to find them in the local maven repository.